# copy file to directory in visual basic vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, file-copying

I am tringing to copy files settings.copy from  sourceDir to backupDir but getting error

Dim sourceDir As String = "c:\in\settings.copy"

Dim backupDir As String = "c:\out\"

File.Copy(sourceDir, backupDir)

while executing above script getting below error

**System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'c:\out\'.'**

I already created  c:\out\ folder

Comment: `File.copy` method must specify the destination file, not the destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim userprofile As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)

Dim SystemDir As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemDrive")

Dim sourceDir As String = "y\inbound\settings.exe"

Dim backupDir As String = "AppData\Local\user\default_user\"

Dim root As String = Path.GetPathRoot(userprofile)

Dim useDrpath As String = Path.Combine(userprofile, backupDir)

Dim SysDrpath As String = Path.Combine(SystemDir, root, sourceDir)

Dim file = New FileInfo("settings.cps")

file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(SysDrpath, useDrpath, file.Name), True)

My gole is to copy file from system installed driver to user profile driver

with above code  i am able to copy file

c:\y\inbound\settings.exe C:\Users\pavan\AppData\Local\user\default_user\

please suggested any other better way to do above

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation for `File.Copy`, or even just paid attention to Intellisense?  Both arguments must be file paths.  Neither can be folder paths.

On a related note, why do you have a variable named 'sourceDir' when it's clearly a file path and not a directory path?  If you name things clearly - and particularly not misleadingly - then it's more likely that you'll avoid such mistakes. Of course, using the Help menu or F1 key to confirm that you're using a type of method correctly would help too.